# Insert checkboxlist values to database

Tags: c#, sql

I have a `CheckboxList` in with the days of the week. The user would be able to choose among these days. What I am trying to do is insert the chosen days into a database, a table `days` which contains the days of the week in each column. So when the user chooses Saturday, a value `1` will be inserted to `Saturday` and so on. `0` will be the value for the unchosen ones.

I am using a table adapter for the queries. Is there anyway to do this in short, other than using an if statement for each option?

Comment: What does your code look like now? What is the schema for the table? When the users save, does a single row get added or does one row get added per day option?

Comment: Are you working with Forms or ASP.NET?

Comment: I haven't write the code for this part yet. A single row is added when the user save. And am working on C# forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to not overthink or overdo this. You could accomplish this without needing 7 columns in your table for the individual selections; you need just one, and I'll show you how.

Make an `enum` with the `[Flags]` attribute that contains the days of the week:

```
[Flags]
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
    None      = 0,
    Sunday    = 1,
    Monday    = 2 << 1,
    Tuesday   = 2 << 2,
    Wednesday = 2 << 3,
    Thursday  = 2 << 4,
    Friday    = 2 << 5,
    Saturday  = 2 << 6
}
```

The values must increase by a power of 2 in order for bit-testing to work, which I'll explain later.

Now, bind these values to your `CheckBoxList` however you see fit (basically you would iterate over the enum values with `Enum.GetValues` and add them as your `ListItem`s (using the integer value as the list item value and the enum's `ToString()` representation for the display text).

Then after the user checks their selection, you can iterate over the checked items, logical `OR`ing them together (`|` in C#). This will build a unique value for the day selection. For example, here's the binary math:

```
  Monday     00000010 (2) 
| Wednesday  00001000 (8)
| Saturday   01000000 (32)
             ========
           = 01001010 (42)
```

So you store `42` in your row, and that's it! You can do this in code like so:

```
DaysOfWeek selected = DaysOfWeek.None;
foreach (DaysOfWeek item in list.CheckedItems)
{
    selected = selected | item;
}

Console.WriteLine(selected.ToString()); // see what you've got checked
```

Later, when you read the value from the table, you can figure out which days were checked by testing the bit values:

```
DaysOfWeek valueFromTable = (DaysOfWeek)42; // look up
```

Seeing what was flagged in the enum is easy:

```
bool isMondayChecked = (valueFromTable & DaysOfWeek.Monday) == DaysOfWeek.Monday;
```

Or if you're using .NET 4+:

```
bool isMondayChecked = valueFromTable.HasFlag(DaysOfWeek.Monday);
```

And done. Not a single `if` statement!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I got it, but what if you make the query in `String.Format` and `INSERT` the `ID` he chose as a variable (i.e Sunday is 1, Monday is 2, etc).

Comment: I have think about this way, but the problem I am stuck on how to get them to database table in a single row.